# How to use ngrok to forward traffic to a context path?

Tags: http, webhooks, ngrok

Suppose my web application is being hosted locally at http://localhost:9090/myapp

How do I make ngrok to point to this URL?

Because, if I use `ngrok http 9090` it actually points to localhost:9090.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Probably it is of no value anymore, but I had the same problem.
The solution I found is:

1. Point ngrok to localhost:9090 like you did. Ngrok will give you an address like http://54de4053.ngrok.io
2. Then go to where you're suppose to give ngrok url and add your path to it like: http://54de4053.ngrok.io/myapp
3. You're good to go.

Hope it helps.

Regards

Answer (score 1):

I was surprised to see there is less online than I thought for this.
Only thing I could find so far was making a virtualhost, then using ngrok to point to that... but it must be easier than that.

Comment: I found that forwarding traffic to context path might not be required to be done by ngrok. ngrok can forward traffic to just the port on the local system. Then the web application server can receive the request and handle the requests accordingly.

Comment: sorry @Ahmad I was only referring what I read on google / stackoverflow it was not related to my setup or code.